# clear input fields onsubmit

Tags: javascript

Can you please have a closer look at this source as I don't get any result after submit.
Thank you.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function reset() {
        document.city.citysearch.value = "";
        return true; 
    }
</script>


<form name='city' action='airport.php' method='post' 
    target='result' onsubmit='return reset()'
>

    <input name="citysearch" type="text" 
        placeholder="Name of the city" size="18">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="search">
```

Comment: Does'nt the form just submit, reloading the page etc ?

Comment: What does *"i dont get any result after submit"* mean exactly? What result do you expect?

Comment: Do you have a closing form tag?

Comment: means --> that after submit the other iframe (that has connection with this input field)  ..... should pull out the results and clear the input field....{the search query is already working ....just want to add the clear ..for better outlook .....}

Comment: And there's no need to roll your own. `form.reset()` works out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like incredibly bad practice to have a hidden field named "submit". If you are looking to reset your form fields, try the reset button (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp), no JS necessary:

```
<form name='city' action='airport.php' method='post' target='result' onsubmit='return reset()'>

  <input name="citysearch" type="text" placeholder="Name of the city" size="18">
  <input type="hidden" name="search" value="search">
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**: Sounds like you want to reset your fields AFTER submission. Do this server-side. Try returning the fields that need reset with the attribute value="".

Comment: I think he is trying to clear the field after submitting the data. If so I don't think this is the correct solution since the reset button doesn't submit.

Comment: exactly as matthew said .....first the data is submitted and after that it should clear the input field.....

Comment: Ok. Well, the reset() function you are calling gets executed BEFORE submission, so that's why you don't get anything in submit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly worded, but based off the title I assume you are having problems clearing the citysearch input in the Javascript? If that is the case try something in JS similar to:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("citysearch")
x[0].value = ''
```

Comment: Is your javascript even being run? If you put alert("Test") in it does it fire?

Answer (score -2):

Rather do it like this:

```
  var button = document.getElementById('clear');
  button.addEventListener('click', empty);
  function empty(){
  var input = document.getElementById('text');
  input.value='';
  }
```

Comment: This won't work (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)). Aside from the omission that stops it from working, your answer is essentially the same as [this one from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093490/19068).

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kehehumago/1/edit?html,output is a live demo of your code. It does not modify the input value at all. (It sets the `value` property of the node list returned by `getElementsByName` which has no effect).

Comment: Running the demo I linked to a second time doesn't produce a different result.

Comment: The code in that link doesn't remotely resemble the code in your answer.

Comment: The non-working pile of rubbish in your answer is most certainly not worthy of an upvote.

Comment: But the logic is the same. What on earth do you have against me? I've updated the answer

Comment: The logic is not the same!

Comment: Congratulations, you have finally edited the answer. It still doesn't work. There is no element with the id `clear` and no element with the id `text`.

Comment: He knows what it's supposed to do, the least he can do is play switchi-ditchi with the elements. He can easily add id's